# prevent html injection in CodeIgniter

Tags: html, html-injections

I have develop a site using codeignitor.
 I am able to use security of XSS but I am unable to filter html. 
Which leads to html injection in the form and some message area.
Please tell me how to patch this ?

Comment: Please show your sample code. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: sample code mean. I dont get you.